# htaccess not working at apache 2.4 virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, virtualhost, .htaccess, apache2

Here's my apache 2.4 virtual host config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/fd-pro/app-api/public_html
    ServerName subdomain.domain.com.au
    ServerAlias subdomain.domain.com.au

    <Directory /var/www/fd-pro/app-api/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain-error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have enabled rewrite module also.

And there is an htaccess in /var/www/fd-pro/app-api/public_html

saying

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

But still its not working!

Any clues, please?

Comment: The .htaccess file is actually a hidden file with the name `.htaccess` ; with a leading period in the name, not htaccess as in your question.

Comment: And "not working" means...? Literally nothing happens? Errors? Anything?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use .htaccess if you have access to the main configuration, add your configuration in virtualhost context and it will save you much hassle, but if you insist.

**To answer your qwestion:**
What is missing from that .htaccess you pasted is the directive:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Since loading mod_rewrite is not enough, to "enable" its functionality in your server you must add this directive before you add any others in the context where you want to use it.

**To improve your solution:**
Still, you do not even need that set of "deprecated" method for mod_rewrite since a single:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

in your virtualhost would do exactly the same, without mod_rewrite and without so many directives for one thing.